# Limit the code a plugin can run in dotnet core

Tags: plugins, .net-core

I'm looking at implementing a plugin architecture where I will have end users write plugins that I will execute in the application I'm developing (.net-core 2.0 console application). I load the plugins dynamically at runtime and they implement a plugin interface in a shared assembly. I do want to limit the actions that the user can perform from the plugin and therefore I provide the plugin with an API object. Is there a way to limit the plugin so that it only can use that API? In .NET 4.x I could do this with AppDomains and Code Access Security but haven't found a way to do the same in dotnet core yet. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: One idea is to run the plugin in its own exe with limited authorization...

Comment: I have the same question